# Gmail API Python SDK batchModify not working

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to mark some unread emails as read in a batch request using the Gmail API client for python. This is what I'm doing:

```
response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['Label_8','UNREAD']).execute()
msg_ids = []

for msg in response['messages']:
    msg_id = msg['id']
    msg_ids.append(msg_id)
    # do something with the message

print("Marking messages as READ => %s" % msg_ids)
body = {'ids': msg_ids, 'addLabelIds': [], 'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']}
resp = service.users().messages().batchModify(userId='me', body=body)
print("Response ==> %s" % resp.body)
```

In my test there are 2 unread messages, and the final output from above is:

```
Response ==> {"ids": ["abc123xyz", "abc456xyz"], "removeLabelIds": ["UNREAD"]}
```

...but the messages are not marked as read. There is no error. However, it works if I mark the messages as read individually during the loop using the single version of modify, like this:

```
response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['Label_8','UNREAD']).execute()
msg_ids = []

for msg in response['messages']:
    msg_id = msg['id']
    msg_ids.append(msg_id)
    # do something with the message

    body = {'addLabelIds': [], 'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']}
    service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=msg_id, body=body).execute()
```

But why won't the batch request work? Like I said, there's no error, and I'm using it [exactly as the docs say](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#batchModify).

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I forgot to call `execute()` after the `batchModify()` request. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.